# Javascript - object loop and organizing data within HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops, recursion

I'm trying to loop thro object recursively and output the data in a organized way within the HTML. Below is what i have so far but i'm currently stuck as i can only output the rows but not indentation levels. The sample data in the `preview` element is output representation of what i'm trying to do.

Also if there is a better way to organize/structure the data (via grouping or similar) i would appreciate the suggestion.

```js
var obj = {
    0: {
        "Shirts": 0,
        "Jeans": 1,
        "Brand": "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    1: {
        "Color": {
            "blue" : 1,
            "red" : 0
        },
        "Size": {
            "Man": {
                "small": 1,
                "medium": 0,
                "large": 0
            },
            "Women": {
                "small": 1,
                "medium": 1,
                "large": 1
            }
        }
    },
    2: {
        "Shipping": {
            "overNight": "$ 10",
            "3 days": "$ 4"
        }
    },
    3: {
        "Stock": {
            "Man": [
                {
                    "green jeans": 13,
                    "green shirts": 17,
                    "green shoes": 21
                },
                {
                    "black jeans": 1,
                    "black shirts": 12,
                    "black shoes": 53
                }
            ],
            "Women": [
                {
                    "green jeans": 2,
                    "green shirts": 53,
                    "green shoes": 11
                },
                {
                    "black jeans": 6,
                    "black shirts": 22,
                    "black shoes": 29
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

var dataEl = document.getElementById('data');

var getProperties = function (obj) {
  for (var property in obj) {

    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) continue;

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && obj[property] !== null) {

      if (obj[property].constructor == Object) {
      
        dataEl.innerHTML += '<div class="row title">' + property + '</div>';
        getProperties(obj[property])
        
      } else if (obj[property].constructor == Array) {
        dataEl.innerHTML += '<div class="row title">' + property + '</div>';
        
        for (var i = 0; i < obj[property].length; i++) {
          getProperties(obj[property][i]);
        }
        
      } else {
      
        dataEl.innerHTML += '<div class="row"><span>' + property +'</span>: ' + obj[property] + '</div>';
        
      }

    }
  }
}
//getProperties(obj);
```

```css
#data,
#preview {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  padding: 10px;
}
#data .row,
#preview .row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#data .row.title,
#preview .row.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#data .row.indent-1,
#preview .row.indent-1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#data .row.indent-2,
#preview .row.indent-2 {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>

<!-- This is how it should be structured -->
<div id="preview">

  <div class="row"><span>Shirts:</span>0</div>
  <div class="row"><span>Jeans:</span>1</div>
  <div class="row"><span>Brand:</span>Lorem ipsum</div>
  
  <div class="row title">Color</div>
  <div class="row indent-1"><span>blue:</span> 1</div>
  <div class="row indent-1"><span>red:</span> 0</div>
  
  <div class="row title">Size</div>
  <div class="row title indent-1">Man</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>small:</span> 1</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>medium:</span> 0</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>large:</span> 0</div>
  <div class="row title indent-1">Women</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>small:</span> 1</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>medium:</span> 1</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>large:</span> 1</div>
  
  <div class="row title">Shipping</div>
  <div class="row indent-1"><span>overNight:</span> $ 10</div>
  <div class="row indent-1"><span>3 days:</span> $ 4</div>
  
  <div class="row title">Stock</div>
  <div class="row title indent-1">Man</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>green jeans:</span> 13</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>green shirts:</span> 17</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>green shoes:</span> 21</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>black jeans:</span> 1</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>black shirts:</span> 127</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>black shoes:</span> 53</div>
  <div class="row title indent-1">Women</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>green jeans:</span> 2</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>green shirts:</span> 53</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>green shoes:</span> 11</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>black jeans:</span> 6</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>black shirts:</span> 22</div>
  <div class="row indent-2"><span>black shoes:</span> 29</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/KJQ9K/554/ ? Just to pretty print the JSON?

Comment: No, i need to represent it within the html so i can manipulate the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using a recursive function for html construction, instead of appending the resulting strings into an element directly it's better to store it into a variable & return it after the function finishes, which makes enclosing the results in a grouping element much easier - see an example approach compatible with your source object:

```
function getProperties(obj, depth) {
  depth = depth === undefined ? 0 : depth + 1;
  var html = '';

  // first handle arrays
  if (obj && obj.forEach) {
    html += '<div class="list" data-indent="' + depth + '">';
    obj.forEach(function (elems, index) {
      html += '<div class="item ' + (index % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd') + '" data-index"' + index + '">'
        + getProperties(elems, depth)
        + '</div>';
    });
    html += '</div>';
  }
  // the main block (comes after arrays as an array would pass this condition too)
  else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
    // uncomment if you'd like the whole group enclosed in a parent:
    // if (depth === 0) html += '<div class="group">';
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
      html += '<div class="row" data-indent="' + depth + '">';
      if (depth > 0)
        html += '<span class="title">' + key + '</span>'
      html += getProperties(obj[key], depth)
      html += '</div>';
    });
    // if (depth === 0) html += '</div>';
  }
  // else the object is just a value
  else {
    html += '<span class="value">' + obj + '</span>';
  }

  return html;
}

document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = getProperties(obj);
```

You can see inside iterations (the `forEach` calls) I'm just appending result of another `getProperties` call to the resulting string (`html` variable).

Another advantage is that you're not messing with "global state" (#data element's innerHTML), so the function always returns the same results no matter what the element's contents are - that's what's called functional approach.

As done so, nested elements are enclosed in parents, which makes indenting it easier - just set margin-left on a parent element (see the css below).

I replaced for loops with iteration functions (`forEach`) for more functional style and in case of the array to prevent introduction of intermediary variables (`i`), but it's just a matter of preference; also the conditions are a bit different as it's better to use feature detection (does the object have the function I'm going to use, e.g. `forEach`?) `Object.keys` can be used on any object of the `object` type (that's why array resp. `forEach` detection comes before, array is also of the `object` type) and checking on a constructor is not recommended as it can be overwritten by a custom one.

I also added `depth` (that's for the `data-indent` attribute, which doesn't have any meaning here but you might utilise it somehow) & odd/even classes for the groups resulting from array iteration, I think these are quite self-explanatory.

I changed css classes in attempt to make it more contextually sensible, using this css should make it clear:

```
.row {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.value {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.list .odd {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
/* just to see how to target a custom attribute */
[data-indent="3"] {
  color: red;
}
```

(The `data-` prefix for custom attributes is needed to make it HTML validator compliant.)

Comment: This makes much more sense to store them in a variable first. Thank you for explanation and a great solution!